# Find the simplest polynomial kernel for which this data becomes linearly separable

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

This question covers the (kernel) perceptron and requires you to refer to the following training data for parts (a)-(c). You are only permitted to make use of numpy and matplotlib. You are not permitted to make use of any existing numpy implementations of perceptrons (if they exist).

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFNGd.png)

Recall that the polynomial kernel is defined as

[polynomial kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEfaN.png)

Each such kernel corresponds to
a feature representation of the original data. Find the simplest polynomial kernel for which this
data becomes linearly separable (note: simplest in this case is defined as the polynomial kernel
with the smallest values of both m and d).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer if m = 1, d = 3
use logistic regression to solve it

The weights of the final model will give you the values you need